# How to scroll images horizontally in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing simple windows phone application.Can any one please tell me what code should we write to scroll images left to right? and if all images coming from Facebook account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a list of all facebook images and use listbox control to show all images from facebook
for scroll images left to right change ListBox ItemsPanel property.

```
<ListBox
    Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding FacebookImages}" Stretch = "Fill"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo scroll image left to right, you need to write something like that:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      .. put all your <Image Source="..." />
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```